# formal proof that p-values are uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that $p$-values under the null hypothesis are uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$ for an absolutely continuous test statistic $X$.

Proof: By continuity of $F_X$, it is sufficient to prove the case where $p = 1 -
F_X$, i.e. $x \mapsto P_X (X \geqslant x)$. Let $F_X^{- 1}$ be the quantile
function, then $P_X (p \leqslant \alpha) = P_X \left( \left\{ x  :
 1 - F_X (x) \leqslant \alpha \right\} \right) = P_X \left(
\left\{ x  :  F_X (x) \geqslant 1 - \alpha \right\}
\right) = P_X \left( \left\{ x  :  x \geqslant F_X^{-
1} (1 - \alpha) \right\} \right) = 1 - F_X (F_X^{- 1} (1 - \alpha)) = \alpha$.

Is this correct? I'm also unsure whether I'm interpreting what the $p$-value is correctly here, whether it's probability function is just $P_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK; the P-value is a random variable for which
the "interesting" part of the CDF is the 45-degree line
in the unit square.

If you draw its PDF, the rejection
region is to the left of 0.05 on the
horizontal axis. The probability of rejection
is the area of a narrow strip with base 0.05 and
height 1.

The main reference on this is:
Murdoch, D, Tsai, Y, and Adcock, J (2008). P-Values are Random Variables. The American Statistician, 62, 242-245.

There is a related discussion on "Crossvalidated".

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I can't see any proofs on the [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/why-are-p-values-uniformly-distributed-under-the-null-hypothesis) discussion but the extra info on simulation definitely helps!

Comment: @simonzack: The next thing is to look at the distribution of the P-value                                 when $H_0$ is _not_ true. For "far" alternatives, probability crowds into the interval $(0, .05)$ and the distribution becomes far from uniform.